# PHP - check if exist variable in other file

Tags: php, variables

i have this code

```php
if (isset($title) && ($title !== null))
```

And tried this one too

```php
if (isset($title) && ($title === true))
```

but this code dont work becouse it dont check if variable exist and do code in if.
I want to check if variable exist in another file how can i do that ?

Comment: Have you tried moving the if-clause into the other file in which you want to run the check? How did it work? Was that the solution or why wasn't that the solution?

Comment: If the `other file` is not called in any way by the current page/script then any variables you are expecting to find will not have been instantiated. If the `other file` is called in some way then it should be before you attempt to test for the existence of the variable

Comment: first is include if file exists and in this if is this code.

Answer (score 2):

Use `include` **or** `require` before the `if` condition and then try to print if exist:

Example::

```
<?php 
require 'demo.php'; //suppose in this file $title=' Hello world';

if (isset($title) && ($title !== null)&& ($title !== '') ){

echo '$title'; // echo the title here

}

?>
```

Comment: Your Welcome Bro... :) Happy To Help :)